# Adding two arrays together with carryover

Tags: c++

problem is overloading an addition operator to add two arrays together.  The problem for me is dealing with the carryover, if two digits together are greater than 10 than a 1 needs to be carried over to the next addition.  I am not really understanding the math/logic behind the carryover. The arrays can be any size up to 50 elements.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
bigint operator+(bigint lhs,const bigint & rhs){

  int carryover = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < bigint::MAX_DIGITS;++i){
    int temp = lhs.digits[i] + rhs.digits[i] + carryover;

    if(lhs.digits[i] + rhs.digits[i] >= 10){
    carryover = 1;
    carryover = temp / 10;
    lhs.digits[i] = temp % 10;
    }

    lhs.digits[i] = lhs.digits[i] + rhs.digits[i] + carryover;
  }
  return lhs;
}
```

Comment: carry over can be achieved using modulus 10 (`n % 10`).

Comment: What *specifically* is your problem with the carryover logic?  Are you struggling with the size of the resulting array, with the math itself, etc.?

Comment: Go through the problem step by step just like you would on paper back when you were learning math and then follow your own coded instructions step by step and keep an eye out for the differences. You'll see the mistakes you've made  pretty quick.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need those two divisions. The sum of two values that are each less than ten will never be greater than 18. When you add in a carry, the result will never be greater than 19. So once you've determined that there's a carry, `carryover = 1;` is always correct, and `lhs.digits[i] = temp - 10;` is always correct.